# Access reason why slurm stopped a job

Tags: slurm

Is there a way to find out why a job was canceled by slurm? I would like to distinguish the cases where a resource limit was hit from all other reasons (like a manual cancellation). In case a resource limit was hit, I also would like to know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slurm log file contains that information explicitly. It is also written to the job's output file with something like:

```
JOB <jobid> CANCELLED AT <time> DUE TO TIME LIMIT
```

or

```
Job <jobid> exceeded <mem> memory limit, being killed:
```

or

```
JOB <jobid> CANCELLED AT <time> DUE TO NODE FAILURE
```

etc.